# Select an html input element by its current value with CSS or XPath?

Tags: dom, xpath, selenium-ide, selectors-api

Is it possible to select an html input element on its *current* value, using CSS or XPath selectors?

My input control is generated by a React App as

```
    <input name="documents"
    placeholder="Documents" required="" type="file" value="">
```

Or do the document.query… and document.evaluate() functions only query the initially loaded document?

In javascript I can get the current value of an input. But I am trying to write a selector for SeleniumIDE against a React app. My current efforts are

```
xpath=//input[contains(@value , 'document')]
```

or

```
css=input[value*='document']
```

but whereas I can easily select on name, I'm failing to select by value.

In the browser console I find that

```
document.querySelector("input[name=documents]").value
```

gives me a value "C:\fakepath\Upload a document.txt"

but

```
document.querySelector("input[value*=doc]")
```

gives me nothing

Comment: Can you edit your question and show what `<input>` looks like?

Comment: I can! I have! I was sure I'd mentioned it being type=file but … I hadn't :-(

Comment: Something is still missing; the `<input>` element in the question doesn't have a closing tag and doesn't contain `C:\fakepath\Upload a document.txt`.

Comment: Ah. I pasted the markup scraped from the page. (html5 spec is explicit that <input> needs no closing tag). But thank you — you've prompted me to discover via the W3C validator that input type="file" does not permit a value attribute. 

Which makes me suspect that even if dom query can work for other input types, it may not work for type="file"?

Comment: While an unclosed `<input>` tag may be compliant w/ the html5 spec, it's still not well-formed xml which (depending on your xpath engine) may cause xpath expression to fail. If you do close the tag, however (for example, `<input name="documents"
    placeholder="Documents" required="" type="file" value="123"/>`), the expressions `string(//input/@value)` or `//input/@value/data(.)` should (for example, in Base-X) output `123`.